# Path to microsoft-outlook sub-folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook

After finding an outlook item that is located in a sub-folder, I need to see the path to that sub-folder so that I can re-arrange the location of the sub-folder (for example to make it a top-level folder).

Answer (score 2):

As I know, after you find the Outlook item via Outlook search, you could double click on the message to open it in its own window and open the Advanced Find feature via the keyboard shortcut CTRL+SHIFT+F, then you could found its path via Browse button. For more information, please check this [similar issue](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eb718461-a2bd-4734-95a3-e02103363cd3/outlook-2010-searching-for-an-email-where-is-the-folder?forum=outlook).

Answer (score -1):

You can right-click on the sub-folder and show properties. The second property from the top is the location, showing the full path.

Comment: Ah - thanks for replying but you can't click on the sub-folder in the search results list :-( But see the solution above!